# Alignment issue with icon position in mobile web

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, mobile-web, achievements-dialog

There is an alignment issue in the positioning of inbox and achievements dialog box in mobile web.

The normal position of the inbox and achievements dialog icons.

> [image]

When clicking on those the icon position is centralized.

> [image]
>
> [image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is building now.

Mobile doesn't absolutely position its topbar dialogs, so it didn't take kindly to the modal being shoved between the two elements.